# Работа с файлами в Python. Как из данных в файле присвоить переменной только числовую часть

Tags: python

есть файл .txt, в нем записано:

`ticker/price{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '9307.52000000'}`

Как из этих данных, переменной присвоить лишь эту часть '9307.52000000' и так что бы данные в переменной были не списком, а числом ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re

print(''.join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", "ticker/price{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'price': '9307.52000000'}")))
```